# .NET MVC & jQuery-UI form inside a model dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out why I'm encountering this issue.  I'm using a jQuery-ui model dialog box as a pop-up form for updating data.  This works just fine and dandy until I try to place a div inside of the dialog div that contains the actual form.  Opening the modal works fine, but when I press the "cancel" button, I get this error in the javascript console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'
```

Also, the window never closes.  Finally, if I press the "X" button in the top right of the modal, the window will close fine, but I'll get the same error when I try to open the modal again.

Here's the relevant code:

Divs in the view:

```
<div id="TacticInstanceModal" title="Update Tactic">
    <div id="addEditTacticsInstanceContent">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript to initialize the dialog and also populate the inner-div:

```
var addEditTacticInstance = '@Url.Action("Edit", "TacticInstance")';
$('#updateTacticInstanceButton').live("click", function () {
    $('#TacticInstanceModal').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Save: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                SaveTacticInstance();
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $.get(addEditTacticInstance,
        { id: $(this).parent().parent().find('.tacticInstanceIdField').val() },
        function (data) {
            $('#addEditTacticsInstanceContent').html(data);
        });
});
```

Action to load the partial view:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            TacticInstance ti = null;

            if (id != 0)
            {
                ti = tacticInstanceRepository.GetSingle(x => x.TacticInstanceId == id);
                ti.Tactic = tacticRepository.GetSingle(t => t.TacticId == ti.TacticId);
            }
            else
            {
                ti = new TacticInstance();
                ti.TacticInstanceId = 0;
            }

            TacticInstanceViewModel tacticInstance = new TacticInstanceViewModel
            {
                TacticId = ti.TacticId,
                TacticInstanceId = ti.TacticInstanceId,
                StartDate = ti.StartDate,
                EndDate = ti.EndDate,
                CompletedDate = ti.CompletedDate,
                PropertyEnrollmentId = ti.PropertyEnrollmentId,
                TacticName = ti.Tactic.Name

                //TODO: Implement Assets
            };

            return PartialView("_AddEdit", tacticInstance);
        }
        catch (EntityException e)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
            return View("Error");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

Partial View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.Hidden("TacticInstance_TacticId", @Model.TacticId)
    @Html.Hidden("TacticInstance_InstanceId", @Model.TacticInstanceId)
    @Html.Hidden("TacticInstance_PropertyEnrollmentId", @Model.PropertyEnrollmentId)

   <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TacticName, new { @style= "font-weight:bold" } )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Label("TacticInstance_Name", Model.TacticName.ToString(), new { id = "TacticInstance_Name" })
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @style= "font-weight:bold" } )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Label("TacticInstance_StartDate", String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model.StartDate), new { id = "TacticInstance_StartDate" })
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @style= "font-weight:bold" } )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Label("TacticInstance_EndDate", String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model.EndDate), new { id = "TacticInstance_EndDate" })
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompletedDate, new { @style= "font-weight:bold" } )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompletedDate, new { id = "TacticInstance_CompletedDate" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompletedDate)
    </div>
Html.EndForm();
}
```

The strangest thing about this, is that if I comment out the ajax .get in the javascript but copy/paste the generated partial-view HTML into the div on the view, it works just fine.  This leads me to believe that the issue is somewhere in the get but I've tried multiple techniques of injecting the html to no avail.

Comment: try `$('#TacticInstanceModal').dialog("close");` instead of `$(this).dialog("close");`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Tried that and got the same error:  TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'.  I think somehow jQuery loses the handle on the dialog for some reason.  I've doubled checked that I only reference jquery-ui once, and that seems fine.

Comment: Still looking at the rest but a heads up. .live() has been depricated. You need to replace this line: $('#updateTacticInstanceButton').live("click", function () { with: $(document).on('click','#updateTacticInstanceButton',function(){

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  I always forget about the new "on" function in the heat of the moment.  Old habits die hard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need Html.EndForm(); this is producing a second `</form>` at the end of the html output. Also check that your are not returning any javascript libraries in your partial view.

Comment: That did the trick!  I swear I checked to see if there were two form tags and I didn't see another one, but low and behold that did the trick.  Any idea why it was creating a second form?

Comment: Razor should handle the opening and closing tags when you use `@using (Html.BeginForm()){}`.. Glad to hear you got it all figured out :)